# Is It Always Possible to Cross a Surface Exactly Once?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, connectedness

Yesterday, in my physics class, the following question arose:

> Is there a closed surface embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ dividing space into two connected components such that all paths from one component to the other cross the surface multiple times?

Note that one can safely replace "closed surface" with "topological sphere" if they like, since this question concerns only the local properties of the surface, not the global structure. You can see that by noting that, if a path with exactly one crossing exists, then it can be restricted to some neighborhood of the crossing and still be a path from one component to the other, crossing the surface once (that is, the path should being within the surface and end outside, and have exactly one point on the surface).

I haven't much idea how to answer such a question; I note that the Jordan-Schönflies theorem implies a negative result in two dimensions, but this doesn't extend to three dimensions.

Comment: What is your definition of a closed surface?

Comment: @David I'm defining it as a two dimensional topological manifold embedded into $\mathbb R^3$ whose image is compact and who has no boundary. Changing the definition to the slightly less abstract "the image of a sphere under an injective continuous map" (which is not equivalent) is the same for our purposes.

Comment: Okay, but you're not saying it's a submanifold, right? By an embedding you mean a homeomorphism onto a subspace.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I should probably add "connected" as well, though that's implicit in it dividing space into two components

Comment: Your statement that this question concerns only the local properties of the surface is false, because the question is concerned with putative finite subsets of the surface the diameter of which you have no control over. Indeed, a priori I might imagine that no such sphere exists but perhaps some higher genus surface exists.

Comment: I'm not sure I believe this should be an easy/elementary question. As in the now-deleted answer, it would be great if we could pick a path and perturb it so that it intersects with the surface only finitely many times. This is essentially equivalent to what's known as "Topological transversality", which to my understanding was the focus of many topologists, including work by Kirby, Siebenmann, Quinn. That might be the desired keyword: "Topological transversality", and look to see if there are everywhere-wild spheres for which the transversality theorem fails.

Comment: In particular you might find it inspiring to look at the introduction and discussion in Essay III of Kirby & Siebenmann's "Foundational essays". (Or you may not.) If you're looking for potential counterexamples, your embedded surfaces cannot be tame at any point (that is, there cannot be a neighborhood of any point such that the embedding extends to an embedding of the neighborhood cross $I$). So you want to look for "Everywhere wild surfaces". I haven't tried, but [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1250187226) might be a good place to start.

Comment: As a minor upgrade of the deleted answer: If this were possible, then any path from one side of the surface to the other would have to intersect the surface uncountably many times, since it would be a closed subset of $[0,1]$ with no isolated points. This makes me feel as though your question is "Yes, you can always find a path that crosses exactly once", since even though the world is a horrifying place, it can't be THAT horrifying...

Comment: @LeeMosher Are you sure? I'd think that if I had *any* surface such that no path crossed it, I could chop off some portion of it homeomorphic to a triangle and find some open set containing all but its boundary with a homeomorphism to the positive cone of one face of a regular tetrahedron centered on the origin such that the boundary of the patch are three edges of the tetrahedron. Then, just tile four such things together to get a topological sphere with the same property. (I'm not certain that the homeomorphism I want exists, but it seems at least plausible)

Comment: Surfaces such that no path crosses them, if they exist, must be extremely wild objects, even horrible objects if I may borrow a phrase of @MikeMiller. If I may be allowed to speak nonsense, all I can imagine would be something which looks like Alexander's Horned Sphere at arbitrarily small scales near every point. How to cut and paste with such beasts, in the manner you suggest using triangles, would be entirely unclear to me.

Comment: Possibly of interest: If $M$ is a non-compact leaf of the Reeb foliation, then the complement of $M$ in $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ has two path components: The complement of $M$ in an open solid torus, and the complement of the open solid torus. Every continuous curve from one component to the other crosses $M$ infinitely many times. (This isn't a counterexample, of course, because $M$ isn't embedded, only immersed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments, there is an error here. I believe it is salvageable and am not going to make too much effort to correct it.

Yes, this is always possible. Let $\Sigma$ be the surface and $U_1, U_2$ be the two sides it divides $\Bbb R^3$ into.

Invariance of domain (one of the two times we actually use the topology of the surface) implies that $\Sigma$ is nowhere-dense, so any point $x \in \Sigma$ has points in one of the $U_i$ arbitrarily close to it. In addition, $\partial U_i \subset \Sigma$. These sets are, of course, closed (since they're given by $\overline U_i \cap \Sigma$), so we see that $\partial U_1 \cup \partial U_2$ is a covering of $\Sigma$ by two closed sets; because $\Sigma$ is connected, we see that $\partial U_1 \cap \partial U_2$ is nonempty. Pick a point $x$ in this set. (Actually, it should be true that $\partial U_1 \cap \partial U_2 = \Sigma$, but I haven't been able to prove this. Thanks to Milo Brandt for suggesting this way of avoiding needing to prove it.)

Now pick a sequence of points $x_n \to x$, $x_n \in U_i$ ($i$ fixed), and demand that $d(x_n,x) < 1/n$. I claim that for large enough $n$, $U_i \cap B(x,1/n)$ is path-connected. (This is the second place we use the topology of the surface.) This is because $\Sigma \cap B(x,1/n)$ is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\Bbb R^2$ for large $n$. Pass to the one-point compactification. Here $S = \overline{\Sigma \cap B(x,1/n)}$ is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of the aforementioned open planar surface. **I believe one can calculate that it has** $\check H^2(S) = \Bbb Z$, and hence by Alexander duality the complement of $S$ in $S^3$ is two path-connected open sets; but $S^3 \setminus S = B(x,1/n) \setminus \left(\Sigma \cap B(x,1/n)\right)$. Hence $B(x,1/n) \setminus \Sigma$ has two path-connected components; and since I know one of them belongs to $U_1$ and the other to $U_2$ I have the desired claim.

So, supposing $n>N$, $N$ large enough that the above applies, pick a path $f_n: [n,n+1] \to U_i \cap B(x,1/n)$, with $f_n(0) = x_n$ and $f_n(1) = x_{n+1}$. gives a map $f: [N,\infty) \to U_i$, and by construction $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = x$ (taking the limit inside $\overline U_i$). Compactifying we obtain a map $f': [0,1] \to \overline U_i$ such that $f'^{-1}(\Sigma) = 1$. Doing the exact same thing on the other side, we've constructed a path with the desired property.

---

Don't let the fact that this worked out fool you - topological manifold usually behave terribly. As an example of something like the above with the dimensions swapped, Bing constructed a simple closed curve in $\Bbb R^3$ such that there is no disc that intersects it precisely once (and such that the boundary of the disc links with the curve). See [here](http://bit.ly/1TtOBoB).

It's also worth seeing where we can weaken the assumption that $\Sigma$ is a surface. We still need some sort of invariance of domain and a way to use Alexander duality. It is a straightforward modification of the above to prove that you can go between two regions in space, separated by a finite connected 2-dimensional polyhedron, while crossing only once; and maybe one can weaken this to "2-dimensional finite CW complex". (In these cases we *don't* have the property that $\overline U_i \subset \Sigma$, which the original version of this answer tried to prove; but by Milo's argument we don't really need it.)

Comment: Does the fact that one side is part of $U_1$ and the other is part of $U_2$ not follow from the fact that $\Sigma \subset \bar U_i$? That is, we know already that $B(x,\varepsilon)-\Sigma$ contains some $u_i\in U_i$, and thus one of the connected components contains that $u_i$ and thus must be contained in $U_i$ (being a connected subset of $\mathbb R^2 - \Sigma$). There being two $U_i$ and two connected components, they must be correspondence.

Comment: @MiloBrandt: It would if I could prove that, but actually this is the crucial step in finishing the proof that $\Sigma \subset \overline U_i$ - proving that the two sides to this local picture are not both part of eg $U_1$. It's naively entirely possible that there's a point on the surface completely separated from $U_2$. For a picture of a non-manifold where this happens, take -o- as a subset of the plane; elements on the two lines sticking out have this problem that locally they cut the plane into two parts, but they're both part of the unbounded component $U_1$.

Comment: Ah. I'd thought maybe that was a theorem you were asserting rather than something to be proven. In any case, I think your proof work around not having it: $\partial U_1\cup \partial U_2 =\Sigma$ and neither boundary is empty. However, $\Sigma$ is connected, so cannot be written as the union of two disjoint non-empty closed sets, so $\partial U_1 \cap \partial U_2$ is non-empty and if we choose $x$ in the last paragraph from that intersection, things work fine. (Though I agree that a proof showing that $\partial U_i = \Sigma$ would be nice)

Comment: @MiloBrandt: Edited. The answer should now be complete. It's worth noting that thanks to your modification, the proof should work for any connected, embedded, finite 2-dimensional polyhedron. I am less certain but believe it might also work for embedded dimension 2 CW complexes.

Comment: How do you conclude that "$\Sigma \cap B(x,1/n)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ for large enough $n$"? I can see that $\Sigma \cap B(x,1/n)$ forms a neighborhood basis for $x$ in the surface $\Sigma$, and therefore it is homeomorphic to an open planar surface for large enough $n$, but I cannot see to the rest of that conclusion.

Comment: @LeeMosher Argh! I think this should still be salvageable, though - I need to compute the second Cech cohomology of the 1-point compactification, and working through a few examples I'm inclined to believe this might be the compactly supported cohomology of the surface, in which case the answer goes through.